# Complex analysis for real valued integrals.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I'm asked to compute

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x(1+x^4)}dx$$

To do this, I consider the function

$$f(z)=\frac{e^{aiz}}{z(1+z^4)}$$

and the contour composed by the segment on the real positive line going from $\epsilon$ to $R$, the half-upper circumference, the segment from  $-R$ to $-\epsilon$ and the half-lower circumference around zero.
When the radius of the small circumference tends to zero, the border of the contour contains a pole of the function, $0$ in particular. What should I do in this case?

Can you please show me how to compute this integral?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without complex analysis, it is not too hard

Comment: Note that your function $f$ should be
$$ f(z)=\frac{e^{aiz}}{z(1+z^4)}. $$

Comment: Yeah, sure, typo. Could you please show me how to compute it? I lose myself everytime in computation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
$$f(z)=\frac{e^{aiz}}{z(1+z^4)}$$
Let $C_R, C_\epsilon$ to be the half-upper circumferences with radius $R,\epsilon$, respectively and $C_1, C_2$ to the segments from $-R$ to $-\epsilon$, $\epsilon$ to $R$, respectively. For big $R$ and small $\epsilon$, inside $C_R$-$C_1$-$C_\epsilon^-$-$C_2$, $f(z)$ has two poles
$$ z_{1,2}=\pm\frac{\sqrt2}{2}+\frac{\sqrt2}{2}i, z_{1,2}^4=-1. $$
So
$$ \int_{C_R}f(z)dz+\int_{C_1}f(z)dz -\int_{C_\epsilon}f(z)dz+\int_{C_2}f(z)dz=2\pi i\bigg[\text{Re}(f,z_1)+\text{Re}(f,z_2)\bigg]. $$
Note
\begin{eqnarray}
\text{Re}(f,z_1)+\text{Re}(f,z_2)=\frac{e^{aiz_1}}{4z_1^4}+\frac{e^{aiz_2}}{4z_2^4}=-\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{\sqrt2}{2}a}\cos(\frac{\sqrt2}{2}a) \\
\int_{C_1}f(z)dz=\int_{-R}^{-\epsilon}f(x)dx, \int_{C_2}f(z)dz=\int^{R}_{\epsilon}f(x)dx.
\end{eqnarray}
Since
$$ \bigg|\int_{C_R}f(z)dz\bigg|\le\int_{C_R}|f(z)||dz|\le\frac{e^{-aR\sin\theta}}{R(R^4-1)}\pi R=\frac{\pi e^{-aR\sin\theta}}{R^4-1} $$
and
$$ \int_{C_\epsilon}f(z)dz=\pi i\text{Re}(f,0)=\pi i$$
letting $R\to\infty,\epsilon\to0$, one has
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx-\pi i= -\pi ie^{-\frac{\sqrt2}{2}a}\cos(\frac{\sqrt2}{2}a) $$
Taking imaginary parts in both sides gives
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x(x^4+1)}dx=\pi- \pi e^{-\frac{\sqrt2}{2}a}\cos(\frac{\sqrt2}{2}a) $$

Comment: Crap, I haven't thought about doing the integral over $C_{\epsilon}$ with Residues! Thanks a lot! Take a look at my other questions if you can! Thanks again :)

Comment: Which one? Where?

Comment: You can find them on my profile. I have just asked three questions.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{p_{1} \equiv \expo{\pi\ic/4}}$ and
$\ds{p_{2} \equiv \expo{3\pi\ic/4}}$ are the integrand poles in the complex plane upper half. Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\sin\pars{ax} \over x\pars{1 + x^{4}}}\,\dd x} =
\on{sgn}\pars{a}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\sin\pars{\verts{a}x} \over x\pars{1 + x^{4}}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\on{sgn}\pars{a}\,\Im\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\expo{\ic\verts{a}x} - 1 \over x\pars{1 + x^{4}}}
\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\on{sgn}\pars{a}\,\Im\braces{%
2\pi\ic\sum_{n = 1}^{2}
\on{Res}\pars{{\expo{\ic\verts{a}x} - 1 \over x\bracks{1 + x^{4}}}}_{\ x\ =\ p_{k}}\,\,}
\\[5mm] = &\
2\pi\on{sgn}\pars{a}\,\Re\bracks{%
\sum_{n = 1}^{2}
{\expo{\ic\verts{a}p_{k}} - 1 \over p_{k}
\pars{4p_{k}^{3}}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{\pi \over 2}\on{sgn}\pars{a}\,\Re
\sum_{n = 1}^{2}
\pars{\expo{\ic\verts{a}p_{k}} - 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\pi \over 2}\on{sgn}\pars{a}
\left[\vphantom{\Large A}2\right.
\\[2mm] &\ \!\!\!\!\!\left.-\Re\pars{%
\expo{\ic\verts{a}\root{2}/2 - \verts{a}\root{2}/2} +
\expo{-\ic\verts{a}\root{2}/2 - \verts{a}\root{2}/2}
\,\,\,}\right]
\\[5mm] = &\
{\pi \over 2}\on{sgn}\pars{a}\ \times
\\[2mm] &\ \bracks{
2 - 2\exp\pars{-\,{\root{2}\verts{a} \over 2}}
\cos\pars{\root{2}\verts{a} \over 2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pi\on{sgn}\pars{a}\ \times
\\[2mm] &\
\bracks{
1 - \exp\pars{-\,{\root{2}\verts{a} \over 2}}
\cos\pars{\root{2}a \over 2}}
\end{align}